# Repeated addition producing $0$ in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck on the first part of a problem from *Topics in Algebra* by Herstein:

> Suppose that $F$ is a field having a finite number of elements. Prove that there is a prime number $p$ such that $\underbrace{a + a + \cdots + a}_{p\text{-times}} = 0$ for all $a \in F$.

Any hints to get me started? (Please don't give away the answer.)

Comment: @anon: Since the op is only asking for a hint anyway you should just post yours as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show that there is *some number* $p$ such that $\underbrace{1_F+\cdots+1_F}_p=0_F$, where $1_F$ and $0_F$ are respectively the multiplicative and additive identity of $F$. As a hint for this part, consider $F$ under addition to be a finite abelian group.
2. Letting $p$ be the "additive torsion" of $1_F$ in $F$ (called $F$'s characteristic), show that it is prime by exhibiting a contradiction on the opposite hypothesis. That is, assume $p=ab$ with $a,b\ne1$, and deduce that there are two nonzero elements of $F$ that multiply to zero (clearly you want to construct these two elements using $a$, $b$ and $1_F$ somehow..)